# RubyFiddle issue - NameError: undefined local variable or method 'gets' for #

Tags: ruby, input, io, gets

```
class SqrrtProg

  def hello

    puts "Hello! Welcome to the square root program."
    puts "\n Please enter a number: "
    number = gets
    puts number

  end

  def Sqrrt

  end

end

object = SqrrtProg.new
object.hello
```

I am simply trying to use 'gets' to get user input. I had read that it might be because, by default, gets tries to read information from a file. I have tried name = $stdin.gets and name = &stdin.gets.chomp etc... However, I end up at the same error.

Comment: The code is working fine for me, how are you running it? From within an editor or from a terminal?

Comment: I had a feeling the editor may be an issue. I forgot to mention it in my question. I am using RubyFiddle - http://rubyfiddle.com/ EDIT: I just tried it in a console and it worked for me too. It must be a limitation of the environment I was using.

Comment: Rubyfiddle has [a lot](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/1a1e5/5) of problems.

Comment: @MarkieLock, could you please delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question as it has been solved. The code is fine when run from a terminal. This problem apparently stems from a limitation in RubyFiddle. Hopefully this question can help someone who comes across the same problem with the RubyFiddle enviornment :)

Comment: If you accept your own answer it won't show up as Unanswered question!